How can I use datumaro to merge the annotations.xml & video to get a yolo dataset that only has labelded images?
I'm new to ml world, I just found these tow
datum project import --format cvat -n cvat1 annotations.xml
datum project import --format video_frames -n vid1 video.mp4

I found https://github.com/cvat-ai/cvat/issues/1251 this
datum project export -e '/item/annotation' --filter-mode 'i+a' -f --save-images < your_target_format > --

But I don't known how can I achivev this

https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/datumaro/latest/docs/data-formats/formats/yolo_ultralytics.html

Why

cvat is running in docker, slow than host (macOS)
cvat export frame is slow, every export with image need to prepare all frames, even a little label change
I hope I can use the annotations.xml+video/frames to get a faster export
I hope I can use jpg instead of png - MP4 video, jpg is better, png is very large.

